# Web Scraping error in R

Tags: r

I am having an issue trying to scrape data from a site using R.  I am trying to scrape the first table from the following webpage:

http://racing-reference.info/race/2016_Daytona_500/W

I looked at a lot of the threads about this, but I can't figure out how to make it work, most likely due to the fact I don't know HTML or much about it.

I have tried lots of different things with the code, and I keep getting the same error:

> Error: failed to load HTTP resource

Here is what I have now:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

URL <- "http://racing-reference.info/race/2016_Daytona_500/W"
doc <- htmlTreeParse(URL, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
```

If possible could you explain why whatever the solution is works and why what I have is giving an error?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code specifically included RCurl,  but did not use it. You needed to.  I think that you will get what you want from:

```
URL <- "http://racing-reference.info/race/2016_Daytona_500/W"
Content = getURL(URL)
doc <- htmlTreeParse(Content, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks...but that doesn't actually export the data from the table.  Can you help me out with that part too?  I know once I see how this is done I will be able to figure it out, but I can't seem to put 2 and 2 together.